# Regex grep, find $tring and $_tring inside function()

Tags: python, regex, linux, unix

On my debian machine, I'm playing around with some code and regex. So anyway, I'm looking to find the following pattern in some code files:

```
function(some text $tring||$_string)
```

Currently I'm using the following command

```
find . -type f | xargs grep "function"
```

I tried using

```
find . -type f | xargs grep "function(*$string||$_tring*)"
```

but it did not work.

Essentially it needs to search all patterns that match the following rules

- includes function()
- inside function, match the either of the following strings

  - $string or
  - $_tring

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec egrep -Hn 'function\(.*(\$string|\$_string).*\)' '{}' ';'
```

To be able to handle filenames containing spaces, and also if there are a lot of files.

`man 3 regex` if you want to read more about the regex syntax:

```
.            any character, in shell (sh/csh) this is '?'
.*           zero or more any characters
a*           zero or more a's
(alpha|beta) groups, either alpha or beta
^            beginning of string
$            end of string, that's why it needs to be escaped
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you `ack`, it's designed for this purpose (it filters files to not searching in `.svn`, `.git` and such dirs ).

See http://betterthangrep.com/

So :

```
ack -r "function.*(\$[s_]tring)"
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
find . -type f | xargs egrep 'function\(.*$[s_]tring.*\)'
```